# Как Подготовить запрос sql QT?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

есть такой вопрос, хочу сделать UPDATE запрос к базе данных, для этого нужно подготовить запрос, но помимо подстановки данных, я хочу подставить так же имя столбца вот так:

```cpp
query.prepare("UPDATE items SET :n=:m WHERE id=:d");
query.bindValue( ":n", l[2]);
query.bindValue( ":m", l[1]);
query.bindValue( ":d", l[0]);
```

однако, такой запрос не выполняется, хотя если убрать `:n` вот так:

```
query.prepare("UPDATE items SET name=:m WHERE id=:d");
query.bindValue( ":m", l[1]);
query.bindValue( ":d", l[0]);
```

запрос выполняется корректно, мой вопрос заключается в следующем: как я могу подготовить sql запрос подставляя не только данные для вставки, но и имя столбца для вставки?

Comment: `auto q = QString("UPDATE items SET %1=:m WHERE id=:d").arg(l[2]);` подойдёт ?

Comment: Через форматирование строки: `query.prepare(QString("UPDATE items SET %1=:m WHERE id=:d").arg("name"));`

Comment: Имя поля - не параметр, а литерал. И соответственно он должен вставляться как литерал. Либо можно использовать server-side prepared statement (dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего использоваться уже готовую строку и подставить в ней аргументы (на деле QSqlQuery делает это у себя внутри)

```
QString queryStr = QString("UPDATE items SET %1=%2 WHERE id=%3")
        .arg(l[2])
        .arg(l[1])
        .arg(l[0]);
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec(queryStr);
```